# How to create Observable from callbacks called in own threads

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I try to create rx-java wrapper for nu-process (non blocking process execution). And try create `Observable` for std out:

```
static Observable<byte[]> process(List<String> cmd) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {

        NuProcessBuilder b = new NuProcessBuilder(cmd);
        b.setProcessListener(new NuAbstractProcessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStdout(ByteBuffer buffer, boolean closed) {
                //calls on NuProcess thread
                byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes);
                emitter.onNext(bytes);
            }

            @Override
            public void onExit(int statusCode) {
                //calls on NuProcess thread
                emitter.onComplete();
            }
        });
        //start asyncronous
        NuProcess p = b.start();
        System.out.println("Process started");
        emitter.setCancellable(() -> p.destroy(true));
    });
}
```

As you can see all nu-process events calls asyncronous in it's own thread. Basically it's worked. But what if I want run multiple processes serial? 
In that case my implementation broken, because emission happens on other thread.
In code bellow all processes started same time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<String> cmd = List.of("bash", "-c", "printf hello && sleep 1 && printf world");
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();
    process(cmd).subscribeOn(Schedulers.single()).subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

How to implement Observable with "right" threading?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `concatMap`:

```
Observable.range(1, 10).concatMap(integer -> process(cmd)).subscribe();
```

Comment: Yes, but it's work on single chain. What if I want limit process concurrency global, i.e `Schedulers.single()?`

Comment: You can use `Observable.range(1, 10).flatMap(integer -> process(cmd), n).subscribe();` where `n` - number of processes